# Multiple Application running in same mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema, database-schema

I will plan to develop multiple front end applications(150 applications) in monolithic architecture which are hosted in multiple servers and all applications are connected to single database. My objective of this application is each application working together (i.e each application's input and output are dependent to one another). Now i developed upto 10 applications. For this applications, i construct my database schema as single collection schema with different subdocuments. Each subdocument meant different application of schema. Shall i proceed this manner or to change the each application schema as different collection of schema? If i continue with different collection of schema for all application, then summary report of project query involve the all 150 collection of project. Please give your suggestion what way i do this backend architecture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.